# Multicolumn listbox in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, multiple-columns

I have a list box:

```
<asp:ListBox ID="lstAppointment" runat="server"></asp:ListBox>
```

I want to make it multicolumn. I googled a lot but not finding the appropriate answer. I am working in ASP.NET C#.

Comment: You can make your own control containining more listboxes which scroll together.

Comment: It can't be multicolumn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Gridview now for this purpose.